# could you help me fix this css Bug on my site?

Tags: css

Here is the bug I am trying to fix:

[image of bug http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/9008/bild292.png](http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/9008/bild292.png)

I have tried everything and am out of ideas now, here's what it should look like:

[ideal output http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/3508/bild293.png](http://img809.imageshack.us/img809/3508/bild293.png)

The site is: http://mobilova.de/index.php.

Comment: How do you think people can help you fix your site without seeing the code to know what you're doing now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to clear your floated element. You can use a clear fix as others have suggested or you can simply assign `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` to `.inside` and `#red-box`. The only thing keeping #red-box from collapsing is the `min-height`. You will then be able to adjust the margin you have set on the button element and it will now take effect since it has been cleared.

**CSS:**

```
#red-box{
overflow:hidden;
}

.inside{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: nice, you can also use `overflow: auto`, it's better than clearfix approach - ps apply the code to **div#red-box**

Comment: Cheers, I should have also have mentioned that =)

Comment: Looks as though both the ID and CLASS need overflow assigned. The only thing keeping the #red-box from collapsing is the min-height.

Comment: Thank you very much Dan and all the kick ass coders for your suggestions, I will try and see what happens.

Comment: No worries. Remember to mark the answer that best fixes your problem as correct when you are ready =)

Answer (score 0):

Is it trying to float? Add the following div below it:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Otherwise, the height of your button will not push down the rest of the content.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [this clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) to your CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Then, you need to add `clearfix` to the classes of `div#mf15`.  This fixed the issue for me.